# Auto correct spelling while searching a Rails Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way (a gem) to correct spelling mistakes and give similar results when using rails where or find functions in a model?

Comment: a quick Googling gave me this: https://github.com/mezis/fuzzily and this: https://github.com/mezis/blurrily

Comment: can you give some use case or example? In our company's  [website](http://www.fishtrip.cn) we use Solr and Sunspot as full text searching engine, however I don't think that this is what you really want

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going to need a more advanced searching utility than what your database provides out of the box. I would recommend looking into Apache's Solr project, and the [Sunspot gem](http://sunspot.github.io/). I know this can be configured to provide suggestions if a search has a typo.